# Infragistics UltraGrid - Make individual cells disabled

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an order system, where on the order screen, an order can be entered. To do this, it uses an `UltraGrid`, where each row is an Order. See the image below.

[image]

I know that, somehow, it is possible to make an entire row non-overrideable, so that data in cells cannot be edited, and data cannot be entered into empty cells.

However, I need all of the cells to behave like this, except for one, until this cell has data in it. (Eg; all cells except for "Product Code" should be disabled, and then made available for editing once Product Code has been filled in). What is the code I need to do this?

I've tried using a `With` statement to set the cells individually to `ReadOnly` but this didn't seem to work.

**EDIT**

I have used the code below to make individual columns activation disabled, but I get the error message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can anybody tell me why?

```
      If ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Code").Value <> "" Then
            ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(1).CellActivation = Activation.Disabled
            ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(2).CellActivation = Activation.Disabled
            ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(3).CellActivation = Activation.Disabled
        Else
        End If
```

Thanks.

Comment: First thing you should do is change `<>` to `=`, as this is currently setting them to disabled if the value in `Product_Code` is not empty. What happens if you add `.ToString` onto the end of `.Value`?

Comment: @David Thanks, this still gives the same error but at least the assignment is correct now

Answer (score 0):

the approach is correct: CellActivation is the right prop to set.

But I think the problem is **WHEN** you set ;)

You dont talk about WHEN.
If you want that the cells are the set once, the right "moment" the  **`InitializeLayout event`** of UGrid.

In the `InitializeLayoutEventArgs` you will find the `.Layout`, use this to set band-column.CellActivation.

Instead if you want to control a specific cell of a specific row, you need to handle this in `InitializeRow event` and set the Activation of a cell in the row in the eventarg.

While if you need to control the Activation when the user edit cells values, handle it in AfterExitEditMode event.

PS: personal suggestion, use C# instead of VB. more clear, flexible and compact.

Davide

Comment: This has already been answered here, but thanks anyway

http://stackoverflow.com/a/39105251/6634034