# Cannot disable UltraGrid cells

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an UltraGrid in my project. Data can be entered into each cell, which is then saved to the database. I want to be able to disable all of the cells in the current row EXCEPT for one called `Product_Code`. Once data has been entered into the active row column (this is entered via a `ValueList`), I then want all of the other cells to become available for entering data into.

So far I have tried

```
If Me.ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Code").Value.ToString = "" Then
    Me.ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Volume").Activation = Activation.Disabled
Else
    Me.ugProducts.ActiveRow.Cells("Product_Volume").Activation = Activation.AllowEdit
End If
```

But to no success. When the project is built, all of the cells are immediately available to type into, despite no value having been entered.

Why is it not working? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the `DataSource` to the grid bound? If that's the case it may not be editable. Also instead of doing a specific cell you can do columns for ex: `Me.ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(0).CellActivation = Activation.Disabled
`. Also **this works** for me `Me.ug.Rows(whatrow).Cells(whatcolumn).Activation = Activation.Disabled`

Comment: @Zaggler So, if it is, there is no way that I can make them disabled?

Comment: Not if the underlying table is not editable. The reason is because it's bound to the grid and inherits the schema. The only way is to make sure your columns to the `DataTable` are ***not read-only***... On another note, by default ***all cells are editable*** at run time unless it's changed.

Comment: @Zaggler Is there any alternatives to this? I ideally need the `Product_Code` column filled in first, as the others are based upon the data in it

Comment: @Steve Where does the `EditAndSelect` bit go, in the `AfterRowUpdate` method?

Comment: `Is there any alternatives to this?` not that I am aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a previous comment on here that has since been deleted, for some reason... However, one solve you can try is:

- In the form load; add in `ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.CellSelect` - This will mean all of the cells are disabled, but you'll still be able to select the `ValueList` for `Product_Code`
- Now, in the `CellListSelect` event of `ugProducts`, use the following code `ugProducts.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.Edit` (After any validation checks or anything that you have in the method already, it will go in here somewhere, just keep trying things if you aren't too sure where)

Anyway, this should now let you fill them in as you wish.